# Javascript condition evaluation: compare number literal

Tags: javascript

I was writing **`Javascript`** condition:
`"70.5" > "129" evaluate to true, while "70.5" > "729" evaluate to false.` What does this mean?
PS. In the end, I get the code working by `parseFloat(70.5) > parseFloat(129)`. Want to know why I could not compare directly. Thanks.

Comment: you are not using number literals, you are using string literals ... you don't need to `parseFloat(70.5)` since `70.5` is a Number ... as opposed to `"70.5"` which is a string ... so you'll see that `70.5 > 129` is false, and `70.5 > 729` is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that string literals are being compared with one another. While you are writing the number 70.5, JS sees this as a string with characters '7', '0', '.', '5'.

String literals are compared by their [ASCII](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/ASCII.html) codes. So, a character that has a bigger ASCII code will be "larger" than the character that has a lower ASCII code.

Similarly,

```js
var a = "a" > "b";
document.write(a); // Gives false
```

the above code snipped would print false, while

```js
var a = "c" > "b";
document.write(a); // Gives true
```

would return true.

See [this](https://javascript.info/comparison#string-comparison) for more info.